# in the DB2 sql procedure - select query result - if condition - substring

Tags: sql, db2, substring, procedure

i am writing a db2 procedure.
my select query result have date time  which i have to compare.

date format 20120507   time format 111111

am planning to concat both and compare as integer. is that correct way of comparison?

but if it is less than 10  the value will be like 71111 .. am planning to append 0 before time in those cases and concat and compare.

Can i do this in single statement .

```
select dbdate,  if   LENGTH(trim(dbtime))=7   then  '0'||dbtime into newtime   from tablename
```

Comment: No, never compare dates/times as integers, compare them as the proper data type (barring specialized use of a calendar table in some OLAP systems).  Is your data actually _stored_ as integers (or strings), or is that the result of your query?  And what sort of comparison do you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [TIMESTAMP](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/DSNSQJ14/3.2.109?DT=20061213154312) scalar function as in

```
 select  TIMESTAMP(dbdate, dbtime)
```

This gives you a db/2 timestamp that can be used in comparison operations. It is probably best to cast all your date/time values into timestamps then  [truncate](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/DSNSQJ14/3.2.114?DT=20061213154312) or [round](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/DSNSQJ14/3.2.92?DT=20061213154312#TBLWQ431) as required before making comparisons.